# Custom Tumblr them with Handlebars

Tags: customization, tumblr, handlebars.js

Haven't been able to find out any answers to this so far but I'm trying to use handlebars within tumblr's theme system and it looks like my {{variables}} are getting overwritten from tumblr and then my content is never displayed.

For example my handlebars template has

```
<img src="{{bgimage}}" class="img-responsive">
```

But it will output as

```
<img src="{}" class="img-responsive">
```

So it looks like tumblr is just removing it. I have seen others use handlebars within a theme however I just can't figure out how they got around it. Any help would be awesome, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I *think* you just need to add a space to your handlebars template:

```
<img src="{{ bgimage }}" class="img-responsive">
```

Tumblr then renders it as:

```
<img src="{{ bgimage }}" class="img-responsive">
```

`Handlebars.js` should be free to do its thing.

Comment: Worked perfectly, don't know how I missed that. Thanks!