# Instafeed and Tumblr weirdness

Tags: edit, tumblr, instafeedjs

I've run in to an interesting issue where I'm using a Tumblr static page and instafeedjs.
When I'm editing the page Instafeed works fine. However, when I view the page outside of the editor the images don't load and the link won't take me to the instagram site. Here's code, but like I said, everything works fine in the editor.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            var feed = new Instafeed({
                get: 'user',
                userId: USER_ID,
                accessToken: 'aTOKEN',
                clientId: 'cID',
                limit:4,
                template: '<a href="{{link}}" target="_blank"><img src="{{image}}" /><div class="likes">&hearts; {{likes}}</div></a>'
            });
            feed.run();
            </script>
```

Comment: No URL is returned on the live page, inspecting the element returns: { }

Comment: Are you able to inspect the response in the Network tab? Instagram is quite useful if you are making a call from a url and one of the parameters is not quite right (it will display the error in the response). If you are getting a 200 status then the call is OK, so it might be another problem.

Comment: I don't really know how to read it. It just shows the GET with a status of OK, but no images. http://www.spesard.com/about.html is the page if you're curious. I haven't heard back from Tumblr. It's just weird it works in the editor.

Comment: Is there an example of a tumblr site successfully running this code? I ask as instafeed seems to use it's own handlebar style bracket notation {{link}}, but tumblr also uses very similar notation. {Permalink} for example. I am wondering if tumblr is interpreting these tags as it's own. As your rendered markup is showing <img src="{}"> for example.

Comment: It's a custom layout, static page, not a blog, so I figure it should ignore. Also, I'm editing and previewing with their stuff: [screenshot](https://40.media.tumblr.com/5b56c962ba34f0f5a00ba5e19eb55bd1/tumblr_ntae72x6PR1qe7tbfo1_1280.png)

Comment: I'll try and rig something up when I can. The non blog pages still use elements from the tumblr templating language.

Answer (score 1):

Change your template line to have spaces inside all the curly braces:

```
template: '<a href="{{ link }}" target="_blank"><img src="{{ image }}" /><div class="likes">&hearts; {{ likes }}</div></a>'
```

---

Because Tumblr uses single curly braces for its themes (ex: `{SubmitLabel}`), it sees your template line an treats `{{link}}` as a theme variable.

You can trick Tumblr into ignoring those tags by adding spaces inside the curly braces.

For reference, see:

- https://github.com/stevenschobert/instafeed.js/issues/41
- [Custom Tumblr them with Handlebars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23024632/custom-tumblr-them-with-handlebars)

Comment: Cool. Thanks, Steven.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I just got back to it, and as [lharby](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1238244/lharby) suggested, it is in fact the use of the "template:" that causes the problem. Lots of thanks, now I just have to figure out a work around.

Thanks again,

...still think it's weird that it works in the editor... :^/